# Conductivity and Molar Conductivity of Equimolar Solutions of LiCl and KCl

Tags: electrochemistry, conductivity

If one took equimolar solutions of $\ce{Li}$ and $\ce{K}$, which would have higher conductivity? Is it the same for molar conductivity?

Say, $\ce{LiCl}$ and $\ce{KCl}$, of a litre each. Also, as Molar Conductivity = Conductivity / Molarity, are molar conductivity and conductivity directly proportional? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Since Li is highly solvated due to its small size, it's mobility is reduced and hence conductivity decreased.

Comment: I'm fine with this answer, but it would really pay if you be a little more elaborate. It might give some people a comment-like feeling.

Comment: Hmm, don't remember it now. :) I think I did click *looks OK*, but a better answer garners more votes, ya know. :)

Comment: Oh well, just saying. I think only a sentence can't help the OP (and they might be too shy to ask in their own post as a comment) You can leave this as is, or you can add a canonical and a comprehensive answer so that everyone else will be benefited. Oooh man! Now *that* will be helping. :)

Comment: @MARamezani :D I was earlier going to post `Since Li has less mobility, it has less conductivity`. I think it's enough and galdful that I added `due to...`